# ¿Cómo puedo hacer el module.export para el pool en postgres?

Tags: nodejs, postgresql, sql, express

He tenido problemas para poder utilizar la constante "pool" que me perdite utilizar la función query de Postgres.Tengo la configuración de mi base de datos en:

`src\db\index.js`:

```
const {Pool} = require('pg');
const express = require('express');
//Initialize
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const fetch = require('fetch');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
//Global Variables
const pool = new Pool({
    connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    ssl:true
});
//Setting
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
//Routes
app.use(require('../Routes/logIn'));
app.use(require('../Routes/singIn'));
app.use(require('../Routes/forgotPass.js'));
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${PORT}`));
module.exports = pool;
```

Y quiero llamar a la constante pool en mi ruta:

`src\Routes\LogIn.js`:

```
const express = require('express');
const pool = require('../db');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/usuario/:user', function (req, res) {
    //console.log("GET usuario");
    var user = req.params.user;
    pool.query(
        `select * from users where email = '${user}' limit 1`,
        function (error, resq, fields) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                console.log(user);
                res.send(resq.rows);
            }
        }
    );
});

module.exports = router;
```

Pero al ejecutar el código, me dice que pool.query no es una función.

Quisiera saber si alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: Hola, puedes proporcionar la totalidad del código, ya que veo que faltan algunos importes de librerías.

Comment: Perdon, me acabo de enterar. Ya subi lo que faltaba

Comment: Algo que no logro entender, es porque en el archivo ```src/db/index.js``` inicias tu servidor express, no deberías de en este archivo iniciar la conexión de postgres. Es solo mera curiosidad para entender mejor el codigo.

Comment: Lo que decidimos hacer era el enrutamientos y el servidor en el mismo para tenerlas cosas en el mismo espacio, o es mas recomendable hacerlo por separado? Soy bastante nuevo en aplicaciones web y aun mas en back-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalmente en un servidor en nodejs con express y cualquier base de datos, se estructura así. De modo que cada script tenga una función en concreto.

Aquí tenemos la conexión a la base de datos en el siguiente archivo `src/helpers/db.js`

```
const { Pool } = require("pg");

const pool = new Pool({
  connectionString: "postgres://[user]:[password]@[host]:[port]/[database]"
});

module.exports = pool;
```

El enrutador `src/routers/router.js`

```
const { Router } = require("express");
const db = require("./db");

const router = Router();

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  db.query("SELECT NOW()", (err, query) => {
    if (err) return res.status(500).end();

    console.log(query);
    res.send("Hey Router");
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Y por ultimo el archivo principal de inicio del servidor `src/index.js`

```
const express = require("express");

const db = require("./db");
const router = require("./router");

const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("Hello World!"));

app.use("/router", router);

app.listen(8080, () => {
  db.connect((err, client) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err);

    console.log("connected to the db");
  });

  console.log("Listen port 8080");
});
```

Espero que te sirva de algo esta solución, y suerte!.

Comment: Que diferencia hay en poner los servidores por separado?

Comment: Servidores por separado, creo que estas equivocado, los hay un servidor el cual inicia en la parte de ```app.listen()``` en el archivo ```src/index.js```.

Comment: Los demás archivos como ```src/db.js``` y ```src/routers/router.js```, cada uno tiene una función por separado, en otras palabras es un modulo. Lo que quiere decir que va realizar un tarea en especifico. Ya sea en el caso de ```src/db.js``` que va conectar a la base de datos, y el otro caso  ```src/routers/router.js``` va a definir nuevas rutas al servidor.

Comment: En cuanto a porque se divide, es para mantener orden y buena legibilidad del código, y no tener un código espagueti.

Comment: Listo, ahora que tenga la posibilidad de modificar el codigo, lo probare! Gracias

Comment: Ok, cualquier intercado lo comentas. Suerte!.